# Deletion of line in vi editor,if particuar string(till the end of line.) matches

Tags: linux, editor, vi

In vi editor,If particular string matches,than delete those string till the end of line.
means if line is

```
"I found a good solution for my bill printing task and it is working properly for me."
```

and string which is going to check in file is

```
"working properly"
```

than output will be

```
"I found a good solution for my bill printing task and it is "
```

I know How to delete last character of  each line in file, then command :-- esc:%s/.$//g
but i have to issue this command again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the string you want to match at the beginning of the regular expression:

```
%s/working properly.*//
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe using

`%s/\<working properly.*//g`

would be appropriate. It would match only the complete word.

For example: it would match *working properly* but not *networking properly*.